# Python Tkinter - Unable to obtain entry value after widgets in window are destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a program using Tkinter that prompts the user to enter their name as a value, then displays it after the contents of the window are cleared. However, I'm unable to retrieve this value. I'd like to know how I could fix this.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinter

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.main_window.title("Window Title")

        self.main_window.geometry("300x100")


        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.frame,
                                    text="Enter name:")
        self.label1.pack(pady=5)

        self.name_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frame,
                                        width=20)
        self.name_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.name = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.name_label = tkinter.Label(self.frame,
                                        textvariable=self.name)

        def frame2():
            for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            self.frame.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack(pady=20) 

        self.name_enter = tkinter.Button(self.frame,
                                        text="Confirm",
                                        command=lambda:
                                        [self.getname(),frame2()])

        self.name_enter.pack(pady=5)

        self.frame.pack()

        self.frame2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.frame2,
                                    text="Your name is " +
                                    str(self.name.get()) +
                                    ".")
        self.label2.pack(pady=5)

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def getname(self):
        nameget = str(self.name_entry.get())
        self.name.set(nameget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
```

Comment: You are setting the text of `label2` *as the window is being created* - the user hasn't clicked the Button yet, and certainly has had no chance to type their name in, so it's obviously going to be blank.  You already have a `StringVar` that gets set to the entered name, just use `textvariable=` to have the label display that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion from jasonharper I edit the code for a possible fix.  I added another label above your label that takes in the StringVar() and then changed the label parameters to textvariable=self.name which gets the input.

```
import tkinter

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.main_window.title("Window Title")

        self.main_window.geometry("300x100")


        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.frame,
                                    text="Enter name:")
        self.label1.pack(pady=5)

        self.name_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frame,
                                        width=20)
        self.name_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.name = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.name_label = tkinter.Label(self.frame,
                                        textvariable=self.name)

        def frame2():
            for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            self.frame.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack(pady=20) 

        self.name_enter = tkinter.Button(self.frame,
                                        text="Confirm",
                                        command=lambda:
                                        [self.getname(),frame2()])

        self.name_enter.pack(pady=5)

        self.frame.pack()

        self.frame2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.labelx = tkinter.Label(self.frame2, text="Your name is")
        self.labelx.pack()

        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.name)
        self.label2.pack(pady=5)

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def getname(self):
        nameget = str(self.name_entry.get())
        self.name.set(nameget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
```

Answer (score 0):

> that prompts the user to enter their name as a value, then displays it
> after the contents of the window are cleared.

The correct way to do this.

Just three minors changed.

- In line 45, remove keyword `text=` in `Label` widget.
- In line 52, comment out `#self.name.set(nameget)`
- In line 53, add `self.label2['text'] = f"Your name is {nameget}"`
  #using f-string format.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.main_window.title("Window Title")

        self.main_window.geometry("300x100")


        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.frame,
                                    text="Enter name:")
        self.label1.pack(pady=5)

        self.name_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frame,
                                        width=20)
        self.name_entry.pack(pady=5)

        self.name = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.name_label = tkinter.Label(self.frame,
                                        textvariable=self.name)

        def frame2():
            for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            self.frame.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack(pady=20) 

        self.name_enter = tkinter.Button(self.frame,
                                        text="Confirm",
                                        command=lambda:
                                        [self.getname(),frame2()])

        self.name_enter.pack(pady=5)

        self.frame.pack()

        self.frame2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.frame2)
        self.label2.pack(pady=5)

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def getname(self):
        nameget = str(self.name_entry.get())
        #self.name.set(nameget)
        self.label2['text'] = f"Your name is {nameget}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
```

Screenshot:

[image]